# Python3 and Python2 in the same machine

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, cmd

I read all the topics talking about how to run both of them using Environment ...

But in my case am using a batch script in my ConEmu configuration file

```
if "%python%" == "python3"( 
@set PYTHONPATH=C:\python3\Lib\site-packages; 
@set PATH=C:\python3;C:\python3\Scripts;
 ) else (
@set PATH=C:\python2;C:\python2\Scripts;
@set PYTHONPATH=C:\python2\Lib\site-packages;
 )
```

How to make my code work !

Comment: Batch... in cygwin? Why are you trying to use batch in cygwin?

Comment: Oooh sorry it not cygwin it ConEmu kind of a configuration file in batch...

Comment: You could possibly use [Python Launcher for Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows) instead to choose Python version. Works in CMD console and ConEmu.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Python included `venv`, then something like this might work. This should automatically pick up the Lib directories. Let me know if this does not work.

```
if "%python%" == "python3" (
    @CALL C:\python3\Scripts\Activate.bat
) else (
    @CALL C:\python2\Scripts\Activate.bat
)
```

Comment: Well my problem how I can make this code work I mean when I type in console python2 takes me to python2 Libs automatically I made that code just to get fixed I need how to set and get the value from console command

Comment: I do not yet understand. When you type `python2` or `python3` as a command, do you want the python.exe interpreter to run from the correct version?

Comment: Exactly python2 hello.py goes directly to python2.exe and the same if I type python3 sorry for my English maybe am not giving the right problem that am facing !